# My svg text dissapears when I click on it in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js

I am using d3.v3.js for the transitions. What I am doing right now is loading a rectangle that will be the background for some text. The issue is that in IE when I click the svg area that contains the text the text disappears...sometimes. Sometimes it just flashes, sometimes click a bunch of times will bring the text back.

Playing around with the Debugger in IE I found thatchecking the CSS that affected the text("line-height", "font-size", etc.) would bring the text back and the bug seemed to no longer reveal itself. I tried running this in Edge, 10,    9 with no luck.

I have had no issues in chrome or firefox.

I am also using bootsrap css and and javascript.

This is the function I made to position text and define the content.

```
function infoTextGen(svg,data, containerHeight){
var dat = [];
var type = [
    "Airline: ",
    "System Provider: " ,
    "Partner Type: ",
    "ITCI: ",
    "Interline Baggage: ",
    'Interline E-Ticket: ',
    'Infant E-Ticket: ',
    'Codeshare: ',
    'Ground Handling: ',
    'Seamless Availability Interline: ',
    'AVA Codeshare: ',
    'Direct Sell Interline: ',
    'Seamless Availability Codeshare: ',
    'Direct Sell Codeshare: ',
    'Seat Maps: ',
    'Interline Interactive Seat Assignment: ',
    'Codeshare Interactive Seat Assignment: ',
    'FFP Redeem: ',
    'FFP Earn: ',
    'PNR View: ',
    'Full Itinerary: ',
    'Direct Access: ',
    'CTO Link: '
];
var widths =[];
function pType(name){
    var text="";
    text.fontsize(12);
    if(name === "ST"){
        text = "SkyTeam";
    }
    else if(name === "TCI"){
        text =  "ITCI";
    }
    else if(name === "GH"){
        text =  "Ground Handled";
    }
    else if(name === "JV"){
        text = "Joint Venture";
    }
    else if(name === "ALL"){
        text ="Alliance";
    }
    else if(name === "JV/ST"){

        text = "Joint Venture/SkyTeam";
        text.fontsize(15);
    }
    else{text = name;}
    return text;
}




var yOrN = function(d){
    if(d=="Y" || d=="y"){
        dat.push(d);
    }

}
//Pulling information from
var name = data.Name;
dat.push(data.Airline);
dat.push(data.SystemProvider);
dat.push(pType(data.PartnerType));
yOrN(data.ITCI);
yOrN(data.ITB);
yOrN(data.IET);
yOrN(data.INFETKT);
yOrN(data.Codeshare);
yOrN(data.GroundHandling);
yOrN(data.SeamAvailIL);
yOrN(data.AVACodeShare);
yOrN(data.DirectSellInterline);
yOrN(data.SeamAvailCodeShare);
yOrN(data.DirectSellCodeshare);
yOrN(data.SeatMaps);
yOrN(data.IntInrSeatAssm);
yOrN(data.CSInrSeatAssm);
yOrN(data.FFPB);
yOrN(data.FFPE);
yOrN(data.PNRV);
yOrN(data.FULLITN);
yOrN(data.DIRACCS);
yOrN(data.CTOLINK);




var svgIn =
    //The Catagories of information
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","infoTitleGroup")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(dat)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("opacity","0")
        .attr("class",function(d,i) {
            if(i ==0){
                return "infoTitle";
            }
            return "infoType";
        })
        .text(function(d, i){
            if(d=="Y"){
                return type[i] +d+"es" ;
            }else if(i>0){
                return type[i]+d;
            }
            return d;

        })
        .attr("y", function(d,i){

            return (((i+1)*type.length)/containerHeight)*100 + "%" ;
        })
        .attr("x","10");
return svgIn;
```

}

and this is the code that runs the transitions to display the text

```
infoTextGen(svgInfo,data,590);
   infoTitles = d3.selectAll(".infoType");

   infoTitles.transition()
      .delay(function(d,i){
         return i*20 + 2000;
    })
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity","1");
```

And this is the code for the rectangle

```
 rectInfo.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity","1")
    .attr("fill","DarkSeaGreen")
    .transition()
    .delay(501)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("y",".5%")
    .transition()
    .delay(1002)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("width",divSizeInfo-10)
    .attr("x",".5%")
    .transition()
    .delay(1503)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("height","590");
```

Comment: Please try to put together a [simple working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (working meaning that it shows the bug you want help with!).  Can you reproduce the problem by using d3 transitions on a single SVG text element, without worrying about the data?  Is the problem still there if you exclude the rectangle?  And so on.

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce a small example. The strange part is that I have some areas of the page that have text as well "sitting" on top of rectangles that do not have this problem. This is to say that I have to very similiar situations on the same page with very different results.

Answer (score 3):

I have a JSFiddle to help test this, though it's not using an SVG library: https://jsfiddle.net/f3oyqt2o/11/

Hover on the box at the bottom in IE11, and the SVG's text elements disappear for no reason.

So I think it's not just d3, but a bug involving the SVG element being stretched to fit its container in IE11. The SVG's content will keep the correct aspect ratio and center as expected, but for some reason text is not always working correctly. In this state, if something on the page changes, it may cause the SVG text to disappear.

To fix, I've done various awkward things based on the situation. For the most part it seems the most stable SVG in IE11 is one where its container's height is sized more specifically. Using percentages, and Flex properties like `flex-grow: 1` doesn't seem to work. If I find a good solution, I'll be sure to update. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

adding css property pointer event: none; to the svg element seems to fix it for me.

```
pointer events: none
```